# I want to add Update Button under common/cart without Refreshing using opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add Update button along with quantity input type same as under checkout/cart to cart under common problem is it doesn't come up without refreshing. I want update button to come along with remove button without refreshing

Thanks!!

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: instead i added plus minus button in place of add to cart,plus is working fine issue is with minus .refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564315/add-plus-minus-in-place-of-add-to-cart-in-opencart?rq=1

Comment: @VasK :  Are you want to update quantity without refreshing page ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard yes i am able to increment  but issue is with decrement button ,can you please help