# Add plus minus button below product in opencart 2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart, opencart2.x

I tried replacing add to cart button with plus minus buttons. plus is working fine but having issue with minus 
I did same as given in link below 
[Add 'plus' 'minus' in place of 'add to cart' in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564315/add-plus-minus-in-place-of-add-to-cart-in-opencart?rq=1)

Comment: In which page, you want to add this functionality ?

Comment: in category,tpl instead of add to cart button i want to add plus minus button